# How do I change the shape of my data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have some data in a pandas DataFrame. I have provided a sample of the data below:

```
        V1          V2          V3          V4          V5          V6          V7          V8
ID                              
B7393   7.418801    0.805774    0.837428    0.866967    0.773911    0.825854    0.858694    0.763436
C7096   7.418801    0.857844    0.859367    0.861062    0.804877    0.829015    0.852472    0.763436
```

What I want to do is change how the data is presented into the sample below. How do I go about doing that? I'm new to python and still learning.

```
ID
B7393       
    V1  7.418801
    V2  0.805774
    V3  0.837428
    V4  0.866967
    V5  0.773911
    V6  0.825854
    V7  0.858694
    V8  0.763436
C7096       
    V1  7.418801
    V2  0.857844
    V3  0.859367
    V4  0.861062
    V5  0.804877
    V6  0.829015
    V7  0.852472
    V8  0.763436
```

Comment: Maybe `df.stack()` ?

Comment: What is the "shape of the data below" exactly? A multiindex? Three columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) here:

```
>>> df.stack()
ID       
B7393  V1    7.418801
       V2    0.805774
       V3    0.837428
       V4    0.866967
       V5    0.773911
       V6    0.825854
       V7    0.858694
       V8    0.763436
C7096  V1    7.418801
       V2    0.857844
       V3    0.859367
       V4    0.861062
       V5    0.804877
       V6    0.829015
       V7    0.852472
       V8    0.763436
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Pandas' `wide_to_long()`?

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['V'], i=['index'], j='V_thing')
```

or `melt()`?

```
pd.melt(
    df.reset_index(),
    id_vars =['index'],
    value_vars =['V'+str(i) for i in list(range(1,9))]
).set_index('index')
```